# Background image in Joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla2.5

I am trying to create a webpage like [this](http://davidpattinson.co/education/tutorials/29-how-to-add-a-full-screen-background-image-to-joomla-2-5) (just the screenshot part). I tried to follow that tutorial, plus other on the internet but they don't seem to work. This is my css code:

```
  /* CloudBase 2.0 overrides for Gantry Framework */

/* Basic styles */
body {color: #333;}

 background:url(../images/St%20Pauls.jpg);



#rt-header, #rt-bottom {color: #333333;}
.rt-container {background: #fff;} 
.rt-article a{text-decoration: underline;}
a:hover {color: #000; text-decoration: none;}
#rt-footer, #rt-copyright, #rt-copyright a {color: #333333;}
#rt-sidebar-a {background-color: transparent;}
#rt-sidebar-b {background-color: transparent;}
#rt-sidebar-c {background-color: transparent;}
#gantry-viewswitcher {margin: 0 auto 1em;position: relative;}
#rt-accessibility .button{
  padding: 0px;


}
#rt-accessibility .button, .rt-joomla .icon {
  background-image: url(../images/typography.png);
}

/* Layers structure */
#page-wraper{
  width: 998px;
  padding: 0px 37px;
  margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
  background: url(../images/background/shadow.png) 50% 0px no-repeat;
}
#in-page-wraper{  
  background: url(../images/background/bottom-shadow.png) center bottom no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 51px;
}
#in-page-wraper-2{
  background: url(../images/background/content-background.png);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  min-height: 500px;
}
.rt-container{
  background: none;
}
#rt-mainbody{
  background: #fff;

  margin: 0px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), -2px -2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), -2px -2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), -2px -2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#rt-mainbody .component-content{
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The

```
background:url(../images/St%20Pauls.jpg);
```

part doesn't seem to work for some reason. Apologies if this is a basic question.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check path to image. Open a browser and enter url as:

`http://your_domain/../images/St Pauls.jpg`

if all right you must see the image.

Secondly, you should use quotes for set path to images. It means that you must replace to

> background: url('../images/St Pauls.jpg');

Third, better use name of file that not includes the spaces.

Finally, your CSS is not valid. It must be fixed

> ```
> /* CloudBase 2.0 overrides for Gantry Framework */
>
> /* Basic styles */
> body {
>     color: #333;
>     background: url('../images/StPauls.jpg');
>     position: fixed;
> }
>
> #rt-header, 
> #rt-bottom {color: #333333;}
> .rt-container {background: #fff;} 
> .rt-article a {text-decoration: underline;}
> a:hover {color: #000; text-decoration: none;}
> #rt-footer,
> #rt-copyright,
> #rt-copyright a {color: #333333;}
> #rt-sidebar-a {background-color: transparent;}
> #rt-sidebar-b {background-color: transparent;}
> #rt-sidebar-c {background-color: transparent;}
> #gantry-viewswitcher {margin: 0 auto 1em;position: relative;}
> #rt-accessibility .button{ padding: 0px; }
> #rt-accessibility .button,
> .rt-joomla .icon {
>     background-image: url('../images/typography.png');
> }
>
> /* Layers structure */
> #page-wraper{
>   width: 998px;
>   padding: 0px 37px;
>   margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
>   background: url('../images/background/shadow.png') 50% 0px no-repeat;
> }
> #in-page-wraper{  
>   background: url('../images/background/bottom-shadow.png') center bottom no-repeat;
>   padding-bottom: 51px;
> }
> #in-page-wraper-2{
>   background: url('../images/background/content-background.png');
>   border: 1px solid #fff;
>   padding-top: 25px;
>   padding-bottom: 25px;
>   min-height: 500px;
> }
> .rt-container{
>   background: none;
> }
> #rt-mainbody{
>   background: #fff;
>
>   margin: 0px;
>   -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), -2px -2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
>   -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), -2px -2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
>   box-shadow: 2px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), -2px -2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
>   padding: 6px;
>   overflow: hidden;
> }
> #rt-mainbody .component-content{
>   border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
>   padding: 15px;
>   overflow: hidden;
> }
> ```

If you still not see image you can try use as `background: url('/images/StPauls.jpg');` or `background: url('images/StPauls.jpg');`

Comment: Thanks for ur reply mate. Unfortunately it still doesnt work. I tried all different version that u posted as well. I also uploaded the image on a different server to check it: http://s21.postimg.org/9lywgsn07/St_Pauls.jpg is the image and here is the code:
body 
{
    color: #333;
    background: url('http://s21.postimg.org/9lywgsn07/St_Pauls.jpg');
}


Thanks!

Comment: If you use image from remote server or with full domain name you must specify protocol `http://` or `https://` Example: `background: url('http://s21.postimg.org/9lywgsn07/St_Pauls.jpg');`

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck. Just to confirm, I am using the cloudbase joomla 2.0 template and went into template manager and editedcss/template.css

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure your background declaration is being applied to the body element:

```
body {
  color: #333;
  background:url(../images/St%20Pauls.jpg);
}
```

you will also need to check that the image you specified is correctly located in the images directory

Comment: Hi,
I changed it to : 'body 
{
  color: #333;
  background:url('../images/St%20Pauls.jpg');
}
'
Still doesnt work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The `background` attribute doesn't seem to be contained by any CSS element.  You need to insert it into the appropriate CSS selector element in order for it to be displayed. At the moment the link is just hanging out, not being applied to any part of the document.